How do I use ZLUDA with Coqui TTS on an AMD GPU?
I've been searching for this problem for a long time now. Btw, I'm using an RX570 4gb Sapphire Pulse GPU and there are some guides on how to install zluda with SDNext but I believe that does not apply to my use case. I know that zluda is in it's alpha stage but I wanted to know if it is possible to use it with Coqui TTS. To be honest I don't really know what I'm doing for the most part but, I somehow understand parts of it but not all of it.
So far I've tried following this guide
but I'm stuck with this error

OSError: [WinError 126] The specified module could not be found. Error loading "C:\Users\philip\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python311\site-packages\torch\lib\cudnn.dll" or one of its dependencies.

Please post an error as text, not screenshot.

I just did, I just posted the photo as reference.

Did you find any answer?
